# Fedora 29: Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'fedora-modular'

Tags: fedora, dnf, dist-upgrade

I upgraded Fedora 27 to 28, worked with it a bit (did not run dnf update) and then upgraded to 29. This morning I tried

```
sudo dnf -v update
```

and I got

```
sudo dnf -v update                                           
Loaded plugins: builddep, config-manager, copr, debug, debuginfo-install, download, generate_completion_cache, needs-restarting, playground, repoclosure, repodiff, repograph, repomanage, reposync, system-upgrade
DNF version: 4.0.9
cachedir: /var/cache/dnf
Unknown configuration value: failovermethod=priority in /etc/yum.repos.d/fedora-cisco-openh264.repo; Configuration: OptionBinding with id "failovermethod" does not exist
Unknown configuration value: failovermethod=priority in /etc/yum.repos.d/fedora-modular.repo; Configuration: OptionBinding with id "failovermethod" does not exist
...
repo: downloading from remote: fedora-modular
error: Curl error (60): Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-modular-29&arch=x86_64 [SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain] (https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-modular-29&arch=x86_64).
Fedora Modular 29 - x86_64                                         0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:01    
Cannot download 'https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-modular-29&arch=x86_64': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: Curl error (60): Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-modular-29&arch=x86_64 [SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain].
Error: Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'fedora-modular'
```

The real problem looks like

```
[SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain]
```

The ca-bundle.crt links to tls-ca-bundle.pem and that file

```
205488 Dec 11 14:14 /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem
```

was updated.

I just upgraded to a version that I can't update.

Comment: I have the exact OS setup at home (different hardware) and it works as expected ie 'dnf update' updates. I'm going to create a live usb for 29 and see if that works. I feel painted into a corner, like anything I do at this point will be a wipe and install. I'll ask a different question to see if I can understand the certificate issue: "how can I determine which (where?) certificate in the chain is self signed"

Answer (score 1):

That can be due to a number of reasons. First, you might not have the required keys (happens sometimes). Solution is to install the package with the keys by hand. Or it just happens that you catch the mirror in some inconsistent state, or the repository is being updated. Doing a `dnf update --refresh` usually clears up such hickups, if not, try again in a few hours.

Comment: Thanks, it did clear up at some point. Next time I will remember to use --refresh.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, but it was because my server's CMOS battery was dead and I had to manually adjust the system time to be accurate for the certificates to be valid.
In case anyone else has this problem, and --refresh doesn't help:

Check the time:

```
$ date
```

Then adjust the time as necessary:

```
$ date --set="2 OCT 2006 18:00:00"
```